# Using letsencrypt cert on Istio Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, amazon-eks, cert-manager

I am running Istio 1.5, where SDS is enabled by default apparently, and am trying to enable TLS on north-south traffic in my EKS cluster (v1.15) and I have done the following:

- Followed steps here to set up a sample application https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/
- Installed cert manager 0.15.1
- Created a cluster issuer
- Configured the cluster issuer to attempt to solve the DNS challenge by integrating it with AWS Route53
- Generate a certificate using the cluster issuer and letsencrypt
- Followed the steps here to configure the gateway and virtual service with the certificate created above https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/
- I copied the root certificate of letsencrypt to pass through the curl command
- Tried to curl to the IP of the loadbalancer and I get this error

[image]

Can anyone please guide me on how to resolve this?

Comment: The certificate created in istio tutorial is self-signed, you should use the one issued by let's encrypt for the following steps.

Comment: Can you share how you are tying the let's encrypt certificate to the Istio ingress?

Comment: @KenChen Yep. The cert that is being issued by letsencrypt via cert manager in k8s, right?

Comment: @Rico I am mentioning the name of the secret that cert-manager creates at the time of issuing a cert in the gateway config. Just as mentioned in this doco https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/

Comment: @YYashwanth, In the example, they generate a self-signed root cert and intermediate cert based on the root cert, which is used by istio gateway. Because it's self-signed, you need to include the root cert in your curl command to pass the verification. Since you are using cert from let's encrypt, I think you can omit the `--cacert` part in your curl command.

Comment: BTW, the `--cacert certmanager.crt` is not actually a root certificate.

Comment: @KenChen Yep. I omitted the --cacert argument and it still works (I still get the same error) I was just trying to following the steps as put in the doco. Did not actually think it through like you suggested. Thanks Ken :). I still get the same error. Anything you advise I do different?

Comment: Can you try `openssl s_client -connect <URL>:<SECURE_PORT>` to see if the underlying CA is let's encrypt?

Comment: There is [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/certmanager/) about integration cert-menager with istio. There is full [reproduction](https://discuss.istio.io/t/problems-with-istio-ingress-and-cert-manager/5241/14) made by @chrisnyc with cert-menager and lets encrypt. Take a look maybe you find something useful there.

Comment: @jt97 thank you so much for sharing the discussion on istio forum. That solved my problem.

Comment: However, I have a follow up question that I was wondering some of you can help me out with. If I was to encrypt the traffic originating outside of EKS which is contacting the endpoint within EKS, which certificate do I use?

Comment: @YYashwanth Happy to help, I have posted an answer with that for future visibility. About the follow up question, I´m not sure I understand correctly but this [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is related [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/certmanager/) about integration cert-menager and istio.

### cert-manager

> Configuration
>
> Consult the [cert-manager installation documentation](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) to get started. No special changes are needed to work with Istio.
>
> Usage
>
> Istio Gateway
> cert-manager can be used to write a secret to Kubernetes, which can then be referenced by a Gateway. To get started, configure a Certificate resource, following the [cert-manager documentation](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/certificate/). The Certificate should be created in the same namespace as the istio-ingressgateway deployment. For example, a Certificate may look like:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: ingress-cert
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  secretName: ingress-cert
  commonName: my.example.com
  dnsNames:
  - my.example.com
  ...
```

> Once we have the certificate created, we should see the secret created in the istio-system namespace. This can then be referenced in the tls config for a Gateway under credentialName:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: ingress-cert # This should match the Certifcate secretName
    hosts:
    - my.example.com # This should match a DNS name in the Certificate
```

> [Kubernetes Ingress](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/)
>
> cert-manager provides direct integration with Kubernetes Ingress by configuring an [annotation on the Ingress object](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/ingress/). If this method is used, the Ingress must reside in the same namespace as the istio-ingressgateway deployment, as secrets will only be read within the same namespace.
>
> Alternatively, a Certificate can be created as described in [Istio Gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/certmanager/#istio-gateway), then referenced in the Ingress object:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: istio
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.example.com
    http: ...
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.example.com # This should match a DNS name in the Certificate
    secretName: ingress-cert # This should match the Certifcate secretName
```

---

Additionally there is full [reproduction](https://discuss.istio.io/t/problems-with-istio-ingress-and-cert-manager/5241/14) made by @chrisnyc with cert-menager and lets encrypt on istio discuss, which as @YYashwanth mentioned in comments solved his problem. So if you have similar issue take a look at above reproduction.